# What is the default Hebrew font on android devices?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, hebrew

I've looked all over the internet (page by page...) and still have no clue.
I am developing an app using Jquery mobile and need to know what is the font that is used so I can make css adjustments.
please help.

Thank you.

p.s
I'm testing the app on android 4.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Droid Sans Hebrew is the answer...